# Gravity.RIGHT does not work when anyDensity=false

Tags: android, layout-gravity

I am developing an Android app running on Xperia Z and Xperia tablet Z.
 My problem is that Gravity.RIGHT property is taking effect when anyDensity=true in the AndroidManifest, but it does not work when anyDensity=false. Some rightmost characters are partly hidden as shown below.
 I tried various settings changes in TextView and Layout, but have failed to display them all. Could someone advise me what I should set to make Gravity.RIGHT completely work when anyDensity=false?

Thank you.

`

```
----------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textDP"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="normal"
    android:textSize="15.125dp"
    android:textColor="#0000ff"
    android:background="#cccccc"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50px"
    android:layout_marginTop="50px"
    android:text="@string/Sample001"
    />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textDP"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="normal"
    android:textSize="15.125dp"
    android:textColor="#0000ff"
    android:background="#cccccc"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50px"
    android:layout_marginTop="75px"
    android:text="@string/Sample002"
    />

    : #Omission
----------------------------------------
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If you use android:anyDensity="false". This causes you to go into old density compatibility mode, which you do not want. Instead of setting your text size / layout widths ect. with pt use the density independent dp. cheers

Comment: The mixture of DP and PT is due to my trial and error and I am sure it is not directly related to this problem. Sometimes they are properly displayed, but other times a half of the rightmost characters are not displayed with the same settings. I have no ideta what causes the problem.